# keytool error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: android, ssl, bouncycastle, keystore, keytool

I want to create a BKS keystore type and for that I'm using this command:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore ./test.keystore -alias test -storepass testtest -keypass testtest -dname "CN='', OU='', O='', L='', S='', C=''" -storetype BKS -providerClass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerPath ./bcpkix-jdk15on-148.zip
```

but unfortunately it's throwing:

```
keytool error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

I've tried with some other versions available at http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html
but I'm always getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<strike>Looks like I was using the wrong file. Here it is: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/versionInfo/36621</strike>

Hope it helps you too.

**EDIT:** [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16)

Comment: that is why you do not simply post links

Comment: Using 1.46 version you will not get this error. http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on/1.46/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar

Comment: @GuihE I am getting the same error. Can you please help with the right jar that will help in getting the BKS file

Comment: Use version 1.46 from Maven, it should work: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46

Answer (score 1):

I am on MacOS and I had the same error and my reason was that I was trying to use my path like "~/Download/<*path to my jar file*>" instead of using the full path "/User/<*user name*>/Download/<*path to my jar file*>".

I will just put this here in case someone need it.